# Django 1.10.5: relation 'myapp_mymodel' does not exist even after migrating

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a django app "myapp" with this in model.py:

And in the same folder, I have a `migrations` folder with an empty `__init__.py` and 2 files:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

class Characteristic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    core = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    synonyms  =  ArrayField(
        models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True),
        size=20
        )
```

`0001_initial.py`:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import django.contrib.postgres.fields
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='characteristics',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
                ('synonyms', django.contrib.postgres.fields.ArrayField(base_field=models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200), size=20)),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

Second file:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('myapp', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='characteristics',
            name='core',
            field=models.BooleanField(default=False),
        ),
    ]
```

However, in a view, when trying to create an instance of the model:

```
characteristic = Characteristic(name=attribute.decode('utf-8'), synonyms=[])
characteristic.save()
```

I get an error:

```
ProgrammingError: relation "myapp_characteristic" does not exist
```

I did do: `python manage.py makemigrations myapp` and I have at the top of the file `from myapp.models import Characteristic`

Does anyone know where I'm wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Makemigrations command just creates migrations for the changes in the database. It does perform any type of modification in DB.

```
python manage.py migrate
```

above command does the actual modification in the database and create an entry in migration table. so that Django can understand which migrations are actually migrated